# SDL C++ Application not doing anything when built using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, build-process, sdl

I've just started using C++ again after using solely VB for a year and I wanted to try my hand at cross platform development. So I started learning to use SDL (which is very very easy thankfully) to create simple graphics driven games like Pong and Tetris. I am compiling the code with Microsoft VisualStudio 2010 Enterprise edition, and although my projects debug completely fine, they don't do anything when opened after being built. I know all the resources they use, as they are obviously small and simple apps, and I know they aren't missing any runtime libraries... so I am not sure why they are not working after being built.

The only things I use are the standard C++ libraries (only cmath, cstdlib, and ctime) as well as SDL_TTF and plain SDL. I included all the runtime libraries for SDL in the built executable's directory (even though they are already in C:\Windows\SysWOW64) I've tried running them as an admin and all the other usual Windows7/WindowsVista tricks. Note: I am running Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit. So... I guess I am just asking for suggestions to help me build SDL applications the right way.

Comment: What does "don't do anything" mean?  No SDL window?


Also, post a minimal program that replicates the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it out, stupid me forgot to include the true-type font file I was using. I found this out by writing to a log file every major step. After I noticed the app crashing with `font_load() began... 'timestamp'` written as the last thing in the log file, it was obvious.